# How do I do a simple pivot in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with one column and 5 rows. A `select *` on it gives these results:

```
72594206916
2
1/2/08
Seattle
WA
```

How do I do a simple select from this table into a single row in another table with 5 columns for those values?

Comment: Does order of the columns matter? can you add identity column to this table?

Comment: Queries like these are really only needed in combination with bad Database design. You can only do this with a static SQL query if the number of rows is fixed.

Comment: I agree, popovitsj. I'm just working with what I was given and trying to get the job done. Not happy about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [assuming you'll have only 5 rows in the table]

```
Select * from
(
  select col1, 
  row_number() over (order by (SELECT 1)) rn
  from t1
) v
Pivot
(
    Max(col1)
    For rn In ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
)
as P
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3adc1/9)